# Extend View and Custom Dialogs

Tags: android-layout

I am working on a game where I am extending the view and performing operations in the class. I need to have a popup in the game which will have 3 buttons inside it. I have managed to have the popup show-up using custom dialogs but when I configure the onClick as follows:

```
private void popUp() {
    Context mContext = getContext();
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Cheese Market");
    Button one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstpack);
    one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cheeseLeft = cheeseLeft + 10;
            masterMoveLock = false;
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

It force closes giving a nullpointerexeption even though it is defined in the custom_fullimage_dialog layout.

Can someone help me figure out how to have the button click detected in this scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `dialog.findViewById` instead.
You're setting the contentView for the **dialog**, but by calling `findViewById` you're looking for it under your **activity's** content view.